# Workspaces no longer recognise when an app is already running?

Tags: 20.04, icons, workspaces, dock

Previously when running Ubuntu (20.04 LTS), it used to be that when an app was already open in an alternate workspace, a circular orange marker would appear by the app icon in the dock. If I left-clicked the app icon, I would be moved to the workspace where the app was running.

Now, however, if I open an app the orange marker disappears when I change workspaces. If I click on an app that is already running in another workspace, it opens a new instance of that app in my current workspace. This is very annoying, as though the workspaces are ignorant of one another. ***Edit:*** *I've just found that the app doesn't appear at all in the dock if it's not a favourite. The workspaces are truly isolated.*

Have I changed a setting or is there a package I can redownload to reset this?

I did install a few extensions recently but I disabled them all and restarted my computer, only to find the problem persisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether your dock is set to isolate workspaces:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces
```

If set to `true`, then reset to the default value:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces
```

or explicitly set it to false:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces false
```

Comment: Incredibly grateful, thank you!